# Read email using silverlight

Tags: silverlight, web-services, email, web-applications, silverlight-4.0

Is there any way to develop email client using silver light with the help of webservice. for example,

when i click  "**Get Mail**"  button on the page it should pull all mails from given email id. i heard it can be done using a web service. but i don't have clear picture on that?

can any one give help me to get around this issue?

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. Perhaps you can narrow it down. What e-mail service are you using? Basically, the web service is a gateway. It's an application running on a server that grabs the e-mails on request and sends them to the Silverlight application. There's not much more to it in that aspect - how it grabs the e-mails depends on where they are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jeff pointed out, we cannot give you a solution in a single forum thread.

I'm still going to give you the big picture on how it should be done.

So if you want to build such application, you won't be able to do it directly in the silverlight client because it has limited communication supports (for security reasons).

However, the client has the ability to exchange informations with a web server thru web services (SOAP, WCF,...).  On the web server, you'll be able to install and use any communications librairies (including email management librairies) and then it will be able to get the emails data and send it back to the silverlight client.